# UltraCompare: add preprocessor directives around merged lines

Tags: c++, merge, c-preprocessor

I have to merge some files between latest stable / development versions of our software. So, I opened both versions (the old one, finished) and the new one (development) in UltraCompare (newest version) and I now I need to add several lines from the old one into the new one, but either commented out (prefix: //) or with some preprocessor directives to selectively enable/disable. The directive will always be the same for the whole file.

An example from the old source

```
application->setVersionNumber(KMN_VERSION_LEGACY);
```

needs to appear in the new source similar to

```
#ifdef KMN_ENABLE_LEGACY
application->setVersionNumber(KMN_VERSION_LEGACY);
#endif
```

or in some cases

```
// application->setVersionNumber(KMN_VERSION_LEGACY);
```

Is this sort of "pre-/post-merge" script even supported in ultracompare?

Answer (score 0):

UltraCompare Professional does not have any macro or scripting support.

So it is only possible to merge the different lines one by one manually and insert the preprocessor directives or `//` also manually after each line is copied from file A to file B. It is possible to edit directly in UltraCompare during a file comparison / file merge.

It would be possible to write an UltraEdit/UEStudio script to compare the lines of two files and copy the lines missing in file B from file A with the modification of inserting `//` or the preprocessor directives above and below.